# HTML5 Canvas fire fade around edges

Tags: canvas

I am using the "fire" effect from this neat little code snippet from: http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-fire-effect/ but as I want to use it without the background image I am trying to work out how not to have the hard edge of the canvas around the flames. I have been going through the function but since it is the first time I work with canvas I am not understanding how to control the animation. If  you go on the tutorial link above you will see the full code from the extract I posted below. I believe this to be the part where the flames are actually drawn.

```
function drawScene() { // main drawScene function
clear(); // clear canvas

var data_cnt = data_width * (data_height - 1);
for (var i = 0; i < data_width; i++) {
    out_data[data_cnt + i] = (0.7 > Math.random()) ? 255 : 20;
}

for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < data_width; x++){
        var s = data_cnt + x;

        var temp_data = out_data[s] + out_data[s + 1] + out_data[s - 1] + out_data[s - data_width];
        temp_data >>= 2;
        if (temp_data > 1){
            temp_data -= 1;
        }
        temp_data <<= 0;

        out_data[s - data_width] = temp_data;

        var id = s << 2;
        img_data.data[id + 0] = colors[temp_data].r; // red
        img_data.data[id + 1] = colors[temp_data].g; // green
        img_data.data[id + 2] = colors[temp_data].b; // blue
        img_data.data[id + 3] = colors[temp_data].a; // alpha 
    }
    data_cnt -= data_width;
}

// draw result data
ctx.putImageData(img_data, 0, 0);
```

}

I do not know if anyone can help or at least point me in the right directions. Is there a way of

a) change the "jagged" effect of the flames (like the yellow ones) so as they do not cut off on the edges of the canves

or

b) Make the entire animation softer around the canvas edges or fade?

I have been searching for standard HTML5 canvas flame tutorials online but they are either really complex or really cheesy. If anyone knows of a good alternative, let me know.

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of how it looks and if you can set up a fiddle with your code for us that would be great.

Comment: Hi Ken, I uploaded a ![screengrab](http://www.heydancers.com/uploads/HTML5%20fireplace%20_%20Script%20Tutorials%20-%202013-12-17_15.17.09.png). As you can see the canvas element has hard horizontal edges. I would like to control the flames so that (like the yellow ones) they would not be cut of around the edges. I hope you understand what I mean.